# Pass data UITableViewCell to UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am newbie for Objective C. I have a problem.

I using a custom tableviewcell. I am listing datas with JSON correctly.

I want to pass tapped data to new view's custom tableview.

So i am using `prepareForSegue` method like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"sendIt"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.myTableView indexPathForCell:sender];
        newTableClass *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.testVariable = [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKeyPath:@"tag"];
    }
}
```

When i use this method for passing data to a label inside a viewcontroller; result is ok.
But when i send it to tableview its crashing and iam getting this error:

```
 unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7530f10
```

Edit: Full Error Message is:

```
[ViewController setGUrunMarkasi:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71a8800
```

Where am i wrong. Thanks for your answers...
(Sorry for my bad English.)

Comment: it is looking for a segue called sendIt, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry i wrote false error. I edited error message.

Comment: What is the data type of destViewController.testVariable ? Maybe you need to cast, the object, [[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKeyPath:@"tag"]; to that type ?

Comment: I added @property again for testVariable in base class. Problem solved. Thanks for your ansvers...

Answer (score 1):

The error message you showed is only the last part of the whole error message. It should read something like "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '* -[SOMECLASS SOMESELECTOR]: unrecognized selector sent to instance XXX. So you should be able to identify easily what was wrong.
Also you should set an exception breakpoint: In Xcode, open the breakpoint navigator on the left pane, click at the plus sign at the left bottom, select "Add Exception Breakpoint", and click then "Done". Your app will stop then at the line with the faulty statement.

Comment: OK. Thanks for your reply. Full error message is:[ViewController setTestVariable:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71a8800

Comment: This means you have a class "ViewController" and you want to set a property "testVariable" using the setter method. Are you sure that you declared "testVariable" using @property, and synthesized the accessor methods using @synthesize?